# Python Url API Request with Header - Keep getting Session Expired Can't View Json Data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, request

I'm trying to produce the JSON data so I can search for available camp rentals and the only way seems to be a request with a header otherwise I get a Not Authorize message when just using the URL. Unfortunately I'm having no luck this way as well since I keep getting a Session has expired message. I'm not a web developer so not sure what the cause is. Any help would be greatly appreciated it. Thank you

```
import time
import sys
import requests

url = "https://reservations.piratecoveresort.com/irmdata/api/irm?sessionID=_rdpirm01&arrival=2021-10-26&departure=2021-10-28&people1=1&people2=0&people3=0&people4=0&promocode=&groupnum=&rateplan=RACK&changeResNum=&roomtype=&roomnum=&propertycode=&locationcode=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=WTF&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&masterType=&page=&start=0&limit=12&multiRoom=false"

payload={}
headers = { 
   'authority': 'reservations.piratecoveresort.com',
   'method': 'GET', 
   'path': '/irmdata/api/irm?sessionID=_rdpirm01&arrival=2021-10-26&departure=2021-10-28&people1=1&people2=0&people3=0&people4=0&promocode=&groupnum=&rateplan=RACK&changeResNum=&roomtype=&roomnum=&propertycode=&locationcode=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=WTF&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&preferences=&masterType=&page=&start=0&limit=12&multiRoom=false',
   'scheme': 'https',
  'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'authentication': '',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'cookie': 'rdpirm01=',
  'dnt': '0',
  'referer': 'https://reservations.piratecoveresort.com/irmng/',
  #'sec-ch-ua': "Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99",
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': "Windows",
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',                        
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)


print(response.text)
```

Result
`Session Expired`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting session expired because the session cookie (and authentication token possibly too) are expired. You can fix this using a requests session which will set these session headers for you. Read more here:
https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I made the change and now I get a Not authorized result. Any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: Your authentication token (the authentication header) is likely out of date. There are two ways to go about this, a short-term fix would be to login to the site, go to the request headers in the network dev tools and copy the authentication header. The better solution would be using the session you can log in via requests making a request to the login page with your username and password. If this is done correctly it will set your authentication token for your session. I would recommend using a tool like postman to view the structure of the requests/responses